# Algorithm to check whether simplices intersect nicely

Tags: convex-geometry, simplicial-complexes

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both $3$-simplices linearly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, say with vertices in $\mathbb{Q}^3$ so that we can do computations exactly.  (I am also interested in the generalisations where the two simplex dimensions and the ambient dimension may be different and may be larger, but this will do for the moment.)  Let us say that $A$ and $B$ intersect nicely if $A\cap B$ is either empty, or is a common subsimplex of $A$ and $B$ (possibly of dimension $0$, $1$ or $2$).  What is an efficient algorithm to check whether this holds?  One can try to calculate $A\cap B$ in general by linear programming techniques, but this can be quite complicated, and it feels like there should be something much simpler for this restricted question.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are given by their vertex coordinates, then one could just check if they have a common triangle face $f$ by looking at the subsets of three vertices, and then if the 4th point of each is to opposite sides of the plane of $f$. But perhaps your simplices are not given by their coordinates?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke The vertices are given by their coordinates. I have edited the question to clarify that $A\cap B$ is allowed to be a vertex or edge, which I consider as faces of codimension bigger than one.  Your comment deals with the case where $|\text{vert}(A)\cap\text{vert}(B)|=3$, but the harder cases are where $|\text{vert}(A)\cap\text{vert}(B)|<3$.  In particular, if we find that $|\text{vert}(A)\cap\text{vert}(B)|=0$ it is not clear what is the most efficient way to check whether $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: I see. For $A \cap B = \varnothing$, check if a vertex of one is inside the other. If not, check if an edge of one intersects a face of the other. These checks can be implemented with a primitive that checks if a point is to the positive side of (or on) the plane determined by three other points

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm that works for simplices $\sigma$ and $\tau$ of arbitrary dimension in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Let $C$ be the set of common vertices, let $A$ be the remaining vertices of $\sigma$, and let $B$ be the remaining vertices of $\tau$.  For $a\in A$ put $a^*=(a,1,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{d+2}$.  For $b\in B$ put $b^*=(-b,-1,1)$ and for $c\in C$ put $c^*=(c,1,0)$.  Now enumerate the maximal linearly independent subsets $U\subseteq A^*\amalg B^*\amalg C^*$ with $A^*\subseteq U$.  For each such subset, there is at most one way to write $(0^{d+1},1)$ as a linear combination of $U$.  If there is a solution in which all the coefficients for $U\cap(A^*\amalg B^*)$ are nonnegative, then $\sigma$ and $\tau$ do not intersect in the right way.  If this test is passed for all $U$ then $\sigma$ and $\tau$ do intersect correctly.

Consider the case of two $3$-simplices in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with no common vertices.  There are $4$ sets $U$ with $|U\cap A^*|=1$ and $U\supset B^*$.  The tests for these $U$ check whether any vertex of $\sigma$ lies in $\tau$.  There are $24$ sets $U$ with $|U\cap A^*|=2$ and $|U\cap B^*|=3$.  The tests for these $U$ check whether any edge of $\sigma$ meets any face of $\tau$.   There are further tests with the roles of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ reversed, which brings us to $56$; these are as in Joseph O'Rourke's comment.  One sometimes needs a few extra tests if there are unusual linear relations between the edge vectors of $\sigma$ and $\tau$.  In the generic case we need to do $56$ row reductions of matrices of shape $5\times 6$.  That still seems like quite a lot of work, but perhaps it is unavoidable.

Comment: You might partition the no-common vertices this way: Is $A$ entirely inside $B$? This requires just one vertex check inside $B$. Then: Is $B$ entirely inside $A$? is one more vertex-inside check. Now what remains is: edge of one intersecting a face of the other. But then it must intersect two faces (else a vertex is inside), so you could check three out of four faces and you'd be safe. A minor savings if that matters to you.